# Consistent Issues with Wireless Router when using Zoom

Tags: wireless-router

Not sure if this question is better suited for the normal stack exchange site or this one but I am hoping someone on this forum can be qualified to answer. At my Internet connection at home I have an Actiontec C1900A pair-bonded DSL modem and wirelesss router. Century Link is my DSL provider. While on Zoom calls my Internet connection fails quite regularly while after 20 mintues in a Zoom call. The symptoms are always the same. It first starts with a message in Zoom that my Internet connection is unstable with comments from the meeting participants that I had "frozen up" in the Zoom call. The connection is then lost entirely with the computer saying the WiFi is connected but that there is no Internet connection. My other WiFi devices remain connected to the Internet for a while and then their Internet connection also fails after a little while. Resetting the WiFi Router/DSL Modem fixes the problem.

I suspect that my WiFi router is responsible for the failures and this appears to only happen during Zoom Calls. My question is does anyone know what is causing these issues and if there is a setting in the Wireless router that could be changed to improve my situation.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of suggestions:

1. try excluding the Zoom executable from your AV solution, and retest;
2. reverse the AV changes from step 1, setup a VPN perhaps to IP-vanish or a similar provider, then retest the zoom session.

A quick scan on the make model of modem suggests that it has no settings for speed or a zoom-session, but a deeper dive into their customer support forums might reveal something.

Answer (score 0):

The cause for my issues appears to have been a bad firmware update for my router.  Apparently the firmware update caused a race condition which required me to frequently reset my router.  The issues appears to have been fixed with a new firmware update.